# Laravel working fine with find but it is not working after adding paginate

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

The Table is loading fine without the `paginate(5)` function, but when I Add paginate function then it shows error.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $userid = $request->user()->assets()->get(['id']);
    $arr['love'] = Love::find($userid)->paginate(5);
    return view('admin.love.index')->with($arr);
}
```

Error:

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
(1/1) BadMethodCallException

Method paginate does not exist.
in Macroable.php line 74
at Collection->__call('paginate', array(5))in AssetsController.php line 26
```

Comment: what is the return of `$userid`?

Comment: id from users table.

Comment: I know, is it an array like [1,2,3,4] ?

Comment: Found answer by replacing where by whereIn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer resolved by using whereIn rather where.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
     $userid = $request->user()->assets()->get(['id']);
     $arr['love'] = Love::whereIn('user_id', $userid)->paginate(5);
     return view('admin.love.index')->with($arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `find`, it retrieves a single record. You can not call paginate on a single record. You need to call it on a model builder.

```
Love::where('user_id', $user->id)->paginate()
```

Answer (score 0):

`find()` method only return one result. `paginate` won't work with `find` method.

You could do like this

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
     $userid = $request->user()->assets()->get(['id']);
     $arr['love'] = Love::whereIn($'user_id', $user->id)->toArray()->paginate(5);
     return view('admin.love.index')->with($arr);
}
```

Comment: Working by just using whereIn rather where. Posting answer below.